# Local Protection 0x8007007E - No se puede encontrar el modulo especificado

Tags: c#

El caso es que por error estaba instalando Genexus 15 Server, y bueno, se procedió a cancelar la instalación, lo cual tal parece que derivó en afectar a la licencia de la Evo 3, ya que al ejecutar GX Evo 3, este no cargaba, al ejecutar el License Manager de Evo3, no aparece ninguna plataforma (Development, .Net, Rpg, Cobol.. etc.etc. etc., es decir aparece vacío,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y encima el error:

Local Protection 0x8007007E - No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He reinstalado Gx Evo 3 Upgrade 15 (sin eliminar la anterior instalacion), y nada, mucho agradeceré me puedan ayudar en este asunto, ya que tengo una Kb que depende de esa versión.

De antemano, les quedo muy agradecido por toda su atención y gentil ayuda.

Comment: Búen Día, esto me suena a que tienes que revisar con el soporte de tu aplicativo para que ellos te puedan dar una solución.

Comment: Hola, por favor lee [ask] y de paso haz el [tour]

Comment: Esto es un error que tiene que ver con Genexus,, y creo que la pregunta està bien formulada.